# No saving of text using selenium in python

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
import time
import sys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument("window-size=1200x600")
driver=webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)
driver.get("https://rentry.co/wftw8/edit")
try:

    # here I selected the **span** element that I talk above
    span = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//span[@role='presentation']")))  
    print(span.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
    # change the innerText thwough js
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].innerText="iello cool"',span)
    print(span.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
    # just wait for the id_edit_code to be present
    edit = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "id_edit_code")))
    edit.send_keys("iRfiNq6M")
    s=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "submitButton")))
    s.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    #print the text updated
    print(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//span[@role='presentation']"))).text)
    #print the published and edited time
    print(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.float-right.text-right"))).text)
    
except:
     print("Oops!", sys.exc_info()[0], "occurred.")
finally:
    driver.close()
    print("done")
```

Although the change is reflected when you check using **print(span.get_attribute('innerHTML'))**

But after saving the page by using save button nothing is reflected in the real URL ..
Still old text is there..

I have googled and tried every way I can but still no luck.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: At which step are you stuck exactly? What are the steps involved to reproduce the issue? Do you see any error?

Comment: If we do manually we can change but with selenium the same thing is not happening

Comment: At which step are you stuck exactly?

Comment: There is no error or exception and idk why the new text is not replacing the old one..even though save button is also clicked. I'm not stuck anywhere but the thing is text is not getting updated..!

Comment: you're sending the enter key to the button.  Either send that to the input field, or click the button.

Comment: I even tried click and submit